# How to show $\int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \, d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X f_n \, d\mu$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

$\{f_n\}$ are nonnegative monotonic increasing functions.
Show that
$$
\int_X \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \, d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X f_n \, d\mu
$$

Can someone give me a hint on how to show this?

I know that I can use the monotone convergence theorem, but I dont know how.

Comment: Hint: Consider $g_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_{k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $f_n$ are non-negative, so $g_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k$ is monotonic increasing. Now apply the MCT:
$$ \int_X \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k \, d\mu = \int_X \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k \, d\mu = \int_X \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n \, d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X g_n \, d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_X f_k \, d\mu, $$
where the last equality uses the (finite) linearity of the integral.

Comment: This should do it, thank you. But I have one question: Shouldn't it be $f_k$ instead of $f_n$ in the last term?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks...

Comment: No Problem. Case closed ;)